# How do you fix an error installing GridDb from source on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, griddb

I am trying to install GridDB from source on Ubuntu 18 by following instructions https://github.com/griddb/griddb. Nevertheless, it does not succeed. Here are the logs:

```
top@DESKTOP-JUACTCP:~/griddb$ sudo ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/top/griddb':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```